# Some text boxes doesn't automate

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java, page-objects

> I am automating a scenario. I am using selenium with page object. Here
>   some text fields doesn't enter the value.. There is no error in the
>   program no error in console. locators are correctly mentioned. but
>   still I couldn't get why should not automate the page ?

[image]

Html codes :

```
    Name text :    <input type="text" id="name" value="" name="name"
     class="form-control" />
               <span class="text-danger"></span>

    Name (language) : <input type="text" id="name_locale" value="" name="name_locale" class="form-control">

prefix : <input type="text" id="prefix" value="" name="prefix" class="form-control">

Token starts :  <input type="text" id="token_starts" value="" name="token_starts" class="form-control">

Token ends :  <input type="text" id="token_ends" value="" name="token_ends" class="form-control">
```

subcategory

```
package pageobjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

/**
 * Created by naveen on 5/12/16.
 */
public class subcategoryPage {
    @FindBy(how= How.LINK_TEXT,using ="App")
    WebElement app;
    @FindBy(how =How.LINK_TEXT,using= "Sub Category")
    WebElement sub;
    @FindBy(how =How.XPATH,using = "//*[@id=\'search-container\']/a/i")
    WebElement addsub;
     @FindBy(how =How.NAME, using ="name")
    WebElement name;
    @FindBy(how =How.ID,using ="name_locale")
    WebElement name_local;
    @FindBy(how=How.ID,using ="category")
    WebElement category_dropdown;
    @FindBy(how =How.ID, using= "client")
    WebElement client_dropdown;
    @FindBy(how=How.ID,using ="prefix")
    WebElement prefix;
    @FindBy(how =How.ID, using ="token_starts")
    WebElement tokenstart;
    @FindBy(how =How.ID,using ="token_ends")
    WebElement tokenends;
    @FindBy(how =How.ID, using ="token_avg_speed")
    WebElement token_avg;
    @FindBy(how= How.CLASS_NAME,using= "btn-primary")
    WebElement button;
    public void setApp(){app.click();}
    public void setCategory(){sub.click();}
    public void setAddcategory(){addsub.click();}
    public void setName(String nam){name.sendKeys();}
    public void setName_local(String nam_loc){name_local.sendKeys();}
    public void setCategory_dropdown(String ca) {
        Select cat = new Select(category_dropdown);
        cat.selectByVisibleText(ca);
    }
    public void select_client(String cli)
    {
        Select client_id=new Select(client_dropdown);
        client_id.selectByVisibleText(cli);
    }
    public void setPrefix(String pre){prefix.sendKeys();}
    public void setTokenstart(String ts){tokenstart.sendKeys();}
    public void setTokenends(String te){tokenends.sendKeys();}
    public void setToken_avg(String tavg){token_avg.sendKeys();}
    public void setButton(){button.click();}
}
```

Test case

```
package subcategory;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import pageobjects.HomePage;
import pageobjects.ManageMenu;
import pageobjects.subcategoryPage;
import steps.LoginSteps;
import steps.managesteps;
import steps.subcategorysteps;
import util.DriverManager;

/**
 * Created by naveen on 6/12/16.
 */
public class subcategoryTest extends DriverManager {
    @BeforeSuite
    public void initDriver() {
        //Arrange
        HomePage page = new LoginSteps().Login("geosony", "123456789");
    }

    @Test
    public void verifyValidLoginWithDataProvider() throws Exception {
        //Act
        subcategorysteps log = new subcategorysteps();
        subcategoryPage ex = log.Login("Loan ","English","Loan","Bur Dubai","LLA","123","321","5");

        //Assert
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Hello Sony George"));

    }
}
```

Comment: @Niels van Reijmersdal   Do you know the solution ?

Comment: Can you tell do you call page object class single time in your code?

Comment: @Sagar007   Here i am not copy the code. because there is no error in my code.. other scenarios are working properly. locators are properly mentioned. actually doesn't enter the values in any text box.

Comment: please provide one small sample to add in that element and also the element

Comment: @Sagar007 ya sure don't go

Comment: @Sagar007  hai did you identify the issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49652/discussion-between-antony-naveen-and-sagar007).

Comment: Answer is given Please verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check following line in class `subcategoryPage`:

```
public void setName(String nam){name.sendKeys();}
```

Here as mentioned blank data is entered so Please change this line as per under :

```
public void setName(String nam){name.sendKeys(nam);}
```

And same as other elements.

Please Let me know If any query.